# Looking for an old adventure module - Heroes explore a tower and find a trapped wizard

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, product-identification

I'm looking for an old adventure module and I can't remember the name.

This is what I remember:

- For AD&D 1e, and may have been a DM's Guild publication
- For low level characters, not more than 5th
- Wizard is trapped in a magic circle and begs for help
- One room is a "refrigerator" with a bound ice-elemental to keep it cold
- One room has a pet basilisk, and anti-stoning spectacles hanging outside the door
- Magical "elevator" that goes to every floor of the tower, and one floor is "secret"

#### Clarification

1. I think the cover art was a B&W drawing of a lone medieval type
   tower, with lightning bolts flashing around it.  The perspective has
   the viewer looking up at the tower from the ground level.
2. This is definitely not the Ghost Tower of Inverness.
3. I remember playing this sometime between 1980 and 1990

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thanks for the tip - i added the cover as best i could remember it.  It was pretty generic for a D&D module

Comment: I've never played AD&D, so I can't personally help here - but maybe [this website](https://adventurelookup.com/adventures?q=wizard%20tower&edition=AD%26D) can help you find the adventure? I couldn't find anything within the parameters you provided, but maybe you'll have more luck.

Comment: @PixelMaster thank you for that link, i'll see if it helps.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'm sure this wasn't Ghost Tower of Inverness.

Comment: When asking for product identification, it is best practice to give the earliest date on which you're sure this product existed. Even if it's an approximation like "the last ten years" or "I played this when I was in middle school in the early 1980s."

Comment: Only on the basis of the cover description and the date, if this seems right, let me know and I'll write up an actual Answer. I'm 99% certain it's not the right one, but I spent over an hour looking, so...: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citadel_of_Fire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description sounds like ["Tower of the Stargazer"](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/82999/Tower-of-the-Stargazer).
In the adventure a wizard is trappend inside his tower in a circle of salt and begs the players to free him (although he starts to threaten them if they don't help him).
The tower also contains a magical flying disc elevator and at least one level is only reachable with it, there is a magical refrigerator somewhere too.

The adventure is written for "Lamentation of the Flame Princes", which is a retro clone very similar to AD&D, it is also advertised for low level characters.
The [cover](https://dtrpg-public-files.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/images/2795/82999.jpg) also very much fits the description.

However there is no basilisk in this adventure. Since everything else fits, maybe you misremembered something or mixed up two different dungeons?

Comment: Why are you sure? A couple of sentences describing how it fits the question would be mighty helpful.

Comment: this has some of the pieces, but it's missing the basilisk.  I"ll read it in more detail

Comment: Lamentations of the Flame Princess came out in 2009 and this particular module looks like it was published in 2014. That might help SteveED eliminate this if he is remembering the module from earlier than that. He did say an "old module" which could mean 2014... or it could mean he played it in the 80s.